# For loops and if statements r + preallocation

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

If the value is 1 in EA$phase then the equivalent location in a new vector OCC must be 90. So far I have this:

```
head(EA$phase)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2

OCC <- vector(mode = "list", length = 580) #Pre-allocate OCC
for(i in 1:length(EA$phase)) # For each element in EA$phase
{
  if (EA$phase[i]=="1"){OCC[i]=90} #If the value of EA$phase[1] is 1 then OCC[1]=90
  if (EA$phase[i]=="2"){OCC[i]=90}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="3"){OCC[i]=50}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="4"){OCC[i]=70}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="5"){OCC[i]=60}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="6"){OCC[i]=50}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="7"){OCC[i]=70}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="8"){OCC[i]=70}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="9"){OCC[i]=80}
  if (EA$phase[i]=="10"){OCC[i]=80}
}
```

But this isn't right somehow. Is there a way of making this more efficient/correct? Some trick?

Comment: `EA$phase` has integers (not characters) in your example.   
So you have to compare `if (EA$phase[i]==1) ...` and so on.

Comment: Try making a lookup table like `data.table(V1 = c(1,2,3,...), V2 = c(90,90,50,...))` and then merging this by `V1` and `EA$phase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do without the for-loop (and without preallocation):

```
occ <- c(90, 90, 50, 70, 60,  50, 70, 70, 80, 80)
OCC <- occ[EA$phase]
```

Eventually you want to put the result in your dataframe:

```
EA$OCC <- occ[EA$phase]
```

The used technique is *indirect indexing*: you have a variable (in this case `EA$phase`), whose value is the index for a vector (in this case `occ`).

Comment: Thank you for answering this for me, I appreciate it a lot. Moreover I really appreciate the beauty of the simple solution, it is exactly what I was hoping for. Could you clarify for me what exactly is happening at the second stage please? I understand it works but I don't get the mechanisms (yet) :-)

Comment: Let me do it :) Lets assume `EA$phase[1]` = 3 and `EA$phase[2]` = 5, given that `occ[EA$phase]` will give you 3rd and 5th element of occ, beacuse in fact you will tell R to give you `occ[3]` and `occ[5]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something along:

#### data.table

```
EA_DT <- data.table(phase = c(1,2,1,2,1,3,7,5))

lookup_DT <- data.table(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), V2 = c(90,90,50,70,60,50,70))
res1 <- merge(EA_DT, lookup_DT, by.x = "phase", by.y = "V1")

lookup_DT2 <- data.table(phase = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), OCC = c(90,90,50,70,60,50,70))
setkey(EA_DT, phase)
res2 <- merge(EA_DT, lookup_DT2)
```

#### Even more data.table

```
res3 <- EA_DT[lookup_DT, on = c(phase = "V1"), nomatch = 0L]
setkey(EA_DT, phase)
res4 <- EA_DT[lookup_DT2, nomatch = 0L]
```

#### data.frame

```
EA_DF <- data.frame(phase = c(1,2,1,2,1,3,7,5))

lookup_DF <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), V2 = c(90,90,50,70,60,50,70))
res5 <- merge(EA_DF, lookup_DF, by.x = "phase", by.y = "V1")  

lookup_DF2 <- data.frame(phase = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), OCC = c(90,90,50,70,60,50,70))
res6 <- merge(EA_DF, lookup_DF2)
```

Also `dplyr::left_join()` can be used etc., you just need to make a left join with the lookup table.

Edit: Shorter versions with matching column names included as suggested by @jogo.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this for me, I really appreciate it. It looks like there are many ways of doing this (I'm never surprised but always amazed).

Comment: I'm going to accept jogo's solution because although both work I find (as a novice to r) that I appreciate the brevity and simplicity of the two lines.

Comment: No problem at all, just remember that with @jogo solution the `occ` vector needs to be as long as your highest phase, i.e. given even a single `EA$phase` equal 100 `occ` needs to be 100 elements long, because `EA$phase == 100` would extract occ[100] element.

Comment: ... and with the lookup table you can easily do: `EA_DF <- data.frame(phase = c(100,200,100,200,100,300,700,500))`; `lookup_DF <- data.frame(phase = c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700), V2 = c(90,90,50,70,60,50,70))`; `merge(EA_DF, lookup_DF)` and get expected result.

Comment: or: `EA_DF <- data.frame(phase = c("a","c","e","d","c","a","b","c"))`; `lookup_DF <- data.frame(phase = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), V2 = c(90,90,50,70,60))`; `merge(EA_DF, lookup_DF)`.